# Invalid input syntax for type double precision

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

I've created functions and one of them is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION core.cal_status(
  er_v                 DOUBLE PRECISION,
  cell_v               DOUBLE PRECISION
) RETURNS DOUBLE PRECISION
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE out DOUBLE PRECISION;
  BEGIN
    IF er_v < 15                                THEN out := 'LOW_LOAD';
    ELSEIF cell_v < 60                          THEN out := 'LOW_LOAD';
    ELSEIF er_v > 40                            THEN out := 'CONGESTED';
    ELSEIF cell_v > 80                          THEN out := 'CONGESTED';
    ELSEIF cell_v >60 and cell_v < 80           THEN out := 'HIGH_LOAD';
  END IF;
  RETURN out;
  END;
$$;
```

When I call functions with this:

```
LEFT JOIN LATERAL core.cal_status(
            er_v,
            cell_v) status ON true
```

I got next error:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "LOW_LOAD" Where: PL/pgSQL function core.cal_status(double precision,double precision) line 4 at assignment
```

What is this about, I guess it's something with output type, but not sure.

Comment: IMHO, `RETURNS DOUBLE PRECISION` means you need a double value after `out :=` ;).

Comment: Your function is declared to return a double precision.  The actual type is `text`.  The error is not surprising or misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because the variable `out` is of text type when you do `out :='LOW_LOAD'` and the function is expecting to return a DOUBLE PRECISION.

Try

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION core.cal_status(
  er_v                 DOUBLE PRECISION,
  cell_v               DOUBLE PRECISION
) RETURNS TEXT
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE out TEXT;
  BEGIN
    IF er_v < 15                                THEN out := 'LOW_LOAD';
    ELSEIF cell_v < 60                          THEN out := 'LOW_LOAD';
    ELSEIF er_v > 40                            THEN out := 'CONGESTED';
    ELSEIF cell_v > 80                          THEN out := 'CONGESTED';
    ELSEIF cell_v >60 and cell_v < 80           THEN out := 'HIGH_LOAD';
  END IF;
  RETURN out;
  END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django it happens when you don't migrate after makemigrations